# How to test accuracy manually

Tags: neural-networks, accuracy

I am programing a neural network from scratch in C++ (purely for fun).

My dataset is cut in 3 : 1 train, 1 validation for early stopping and 1 test to measure model accuracy.

I measure accuracy output by output by checking if the obtained result is between a relative range around the expected output. Is that the right way to do ? If the expected value is 0, then the range between 0 is always 0. I dont want to use absolute range because it is scale dependant. How could i do ?

Thanks.

Comment: In a classification problem, the predicted class is taken as the argmax from among the probabilities assigned to each class.

Comment: Thanks, my NN works well for classification, my problem is when i try regression

Comment: That's now how is accuracy used; accuracy measures the quality of a classification model, not regression models. You should use an appropriate *regression* metric.

Comment: Oooh oh thank you i'll check.